# In js/jquery, what is the best way to hide all divs with the same class and content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display only UNIQUE divs that contain text typed in a search field. My HTML contains lots of repeated data (currently very crude). See example data below:

```html
<div class="faq_item">
   <h3><b>FAQ 1</b></h3> <!-- not unique -->                      
</div>
<div class="faq_item">
   <h3><b>FAQ 1</b></h3> <!-- not unique -->                  
</div>
<div class="faq_item">
   <h3><b>FAQ 2</b></h3>                      
</div>
```

I then add the class 'filtersearch' to each item if they contain the text stored in 'searchstring' variable:

```
for (var i = 0, len = $(".faq_item").length; i < len; ++i) {
   if($(".faq_item")[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchstring) !== -1) {
      $($(".faq_item")[i]).addClass("filtersearch");
   }
}
```

This displays only divs that contain 'filtersearch', however, it doesn't hide divs with the same content. Instead of doing another massive loop over every div with 'filtersearch' class, what would be the best approach to only show unique divs?

Comment: You're using `$(".faq_item")` multiple times. You really should store the collection in a variable and then use that variable instead.

Comment: And why do you "extract" the DOM node from the jQuery collection to then wrap it in another jQuery object only to add a class (`$($(".faq_item")[i]).addClass("filtersearch")`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of doing another massive loop over every div with 'filtersearch' class, what would be the best approach to only show unique divs?

You can keep a simple hash object of the text found, hiding any div that's already been seen.

Using vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const faqItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.faq_item')];

function filterAndRemoveDuplicates(searchstring) {
  const foundText = {};
  
  faqItems.forEach(item => {
    const text = item.querySelector('h3 > b').innerText;

    // hide if a duplicate
    if (foundText[text]) {
      item.classList.add('hidden');
      return;
    }

    // add 'filtersearch' class on searchstring match
    if (text.includes(searchstring)) {
      item.classList.add('filtersearch');
    }

    // update hash
    foundText[text] = true;
  });

  console.log('foundText:', JSON.stringify(foundText));
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  filterAndRemoveDuplicates('FAQ 1');
};
```

```css
.faq_item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.filtersearch {
  color: dodgerblue;
}
.filtersearch:before {
  content: ".filtersearch added:";
}
.hidden {
  color: #b0b0b0;
}
.hidden:before {
  content: ".hidden added:";
}
```

```html
<button>Search for "FAQ 1" and Hide Duplicates</button>
<hr>
<div class="faq_item">
  <h3><b>FAQ 1</b></h3>
</div>
<div class="faq_item">
  <h3><b>FAQ 1</b></h3>
</div>
<div class="faq_item">
  <h3><b>FAQ 2</b></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains` and `:first` selector to find first div which has content which is search and hide other divs .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var to_search = "FAQ 1"
var divs = $(".faq_item:contains(" + to_search + "):first").addClass("found")
$(".faq_item").not(divs).hide()
```

```css
.found {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq_item">
  <h3><b>FAQ 1</b></h3>
</div>
<div class="faq_item">
  <h3><b>FAQ 1</b></h3>
</div>
<div class="faq_item">
  <h3><b>FAQ 2</b></h3>
</div>
```